# Is it possible and how to use NGINX for upload files?

Tags: nginx, file-upload, upload

I use NGINX for serving of static files which (it offloads the backend which serves only "dynamic" requests). But now I need to upload files to server. Is it possible to use NGINX for uploading too? Also it will be good if there is a way to set permissions of uploading files... How to use NGINX for uploading? Which protocol? Module? Some example configuration?

I found only WebDAV but its module looks outdated, also I never used WebDAV before so I am not sure how good is it (I mean performance). What is a typical solution? Do I need to write something, some plugin/module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in module to do the job. There is a [third-party upload module](https://github.com/fdintino/nginx-upload-module).